# knockout.js - help dealing with UI state changes when polling for updates

Tags: forms, data-binding, knockout.js

I'm having a problem losing UI state changes after my observables change and was hoping for some suggestions.

First off, I'm polling my server for updates. Those messages are in my view model and the <ul> renders perfectly:

[image: demonstration of multiple items rendering]

When my user clicks the "reply" or "assign to" buttons, I'm displaying a little form to perform those actions:

[image: form displayed on button click]

My problem at this point was that when my next polling call returned, the list re-binds and I lose the state of where the form should be open at. I went through adding view model properties for "currentQuestionID" so I could use a visible: binding and redisplay the form after binding.

Once that was complete, the form displays properly on the "current item" after rebinding but the form values are lost. That is to say, it rebinds, rebuilds the form elements, shows them, but any user input disappears (which of course makes sense since the HTML was just regenerated).

I attempted to follow the same pattern (using a value: binding to set the value and an event: {change: responseChanged} binding to update an observable with the values). The HTML fragment looks like this:

```
<form action="#" class="tb-reply-form" data-bind="visible: $root.showMenu($data, 'reply')">
    <textarea id="tb-response" data-bind="value: $root.currentResponse, event: {keyup: $root.responseChanged}"></textarea>
    <input type="button" id="tb-submitResponse" data-bind="click: $root.submitResponse, clickBubble: false" value="Send" />
</form>
<form action="#" class="tb-assign-form" data-bind="visible: $root.showMenu($data, 'assign')">
    <select id="tb-assign" class="tb-assign" data-bind="value: $root.currentAssignee, options: $root.mediators, optionsText: 'full_name', optionsValue: 'access_token', optionsCaption: 'Select one...', event: {change: $root.assigneeChanged}">
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="tb-submitAssignment" data-bind="click: $root.submitAssignment, clickBubble: false" value="Assign"/>
</form>
```

Now, I end up with what seems like an infinite loop where setting the value causes change to happen, which in turn causes value... etc.

I thought "screw it" just move it out of the foreach... By moving the form outside of each <li> in the foreach: binding and doing a little DOM manipulation to move the form into the "current item", I figured I wouldn't lose user inputs.

```
replyForm.appendTo(theContainer).show();
```

It works up until the first poll return & rebind. Since the HTML is regenerated for the <ul>, the DOM no longer has my form and my attempt to grab it and do the .appendTo(container) does nothing. I suppose here, I might be able to copy the element into the active item instead of moving it?

So, this all seems like I'm missing something basic because someone has to have put a form into a foreach loop in knockout!

Does anybody have a strategy for maintaining form state inside a bound item in knockout?

Or, possibly, is there a way to make knockout NOT bind anything that's already bound and only generate "new" elements.

Finally, should I just scrap knockout for this and manually generate for "new items" myself when each polling call returns.

Just one last bit of info; if I set my polling interval to something like 30 seconds, all the bits "work" in that it submits, saves, rebinds, etc. I just need the form and it's contents to live through the rebinding.

Thanks a ton for any help!

Comment: Please post your view model code

Comment: can you make a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out on my own. And it's embarrassing.

Here is a partial bit of my VM code:

```
function TalkbackViewModel( id ) {
   var self = this;

   talkback.state.currentTalkbackId = "";
   talkback.state.currentAction = "";
   talkback.state.currentResponse = "";
   talkback.state.currentAssignee = "";

   self.talkbackQueue = ko.observableArray([]);
   self.completeQueue = ko.observableArray([]);
   self.mediators = ko.observableArray([]);

   self.currentTalkbackId = ko.observable(talkback.state.currentTalkbackId);
   self.currentAction = ko.observable(talkback.state.currentAction);
   self.currentResponse = ko.observable(talkback.state.currentResponse);
   self.currentAssignee = ko.observable(talkback.state.currentAssignee);

self.showActionForm = function(data, action) {
    return ko.computed(function() {
        var sameAction = (self.currentAction() == action);
        var sameItem = (self.currentTalkbackId() == data.talkback_id());

        return (sameAction && sameItem);
    }, this);
};

    self.replyToggle = function(model, event) {
    // we're switching from one item to another. clear input values.
    if (self.currentTalkbackId() != model.talkback_id() || self.currentAction() != "reply") {
        self.currentResponse("");
        self.currentAssignee("");
        self.currentTalkbackId(model.talkback_id());
    }
```

My first mistake was trying to treat the textarea & dropdown the same. I noticed the dropdown was saving value & reloading but stupidly tried to keep the code the same as the textarea and caused my own issue.

So...

First off, I went back to the using the $root view model properties for currentAssignee and currentResponse to store the values off and rebind using value: bindings on those controls.

Next, I needed to remove the event handlers:

```
event: { change: xxxChanged }
```

because they don't make sense (two way binding!!!!). The drop down value changes and updates automatically by using the value: binding.

The textarea ONLY updated on blur, causing me to think I needed onkeyup,onkeydown, etc. I got rid of those handlers because they were 1) wrong, 2) screwing up the value: binding creating an infinite loop.

I only needed this on the textarea to get up-to-date value updates to my viewmodel property:

```
valueUpdate: 'input'
```

At this point everything saves off & rebinds and I didn't lose my values but my caret position was incorrect in the textarea. I added a little code to handle that:

```
var item = element.find(".tb-assign");
var oldValue = item.val();
item.val('');
item.focus().val(oldValue);
```

Some browsers behave OK if you just do item.focus().val(item.val()); but i needed to actually cause the value to "change" in my case to get the caret at the end so I saved the value, cleared it, then restored it. I did this in the event handler for when the event data is returned to the browser:

```
    $(window).on("talkback.retrieved", function(event, talkback_queue, complete_queue) {
        var open_mappings = ko.mapping.fromJS(talkback_queue);
        self.talkbackQueue(open_mappings);
        if (talkback_queue) self.queueLength(talkback_queue.length);

        var completed_mappings = ko.mapping.fromJS(complete_queue);
        self.completeQueue(completed_mappings);

        if (self.currentTalkbackId()) {
            var element = $("li[talkbackId='" + self.currentTalkbackId() + "']");
            if (talkback.state.currentAction == "assign") {
                var item = element.find(".tb-assign");
                var oldValue = item.val();
                item.val('');
                item.focus().val(oldValue);
            } else {
                var item = element.find(".tb-response");
                var oldValue = item.val();
                item.val('');
                item.focus().val(oldValue);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

So, my final issue is that if I used my observables in my method "clearing" the values when a new "current item" is selected (replyToggle & assignToggle), they don't seem to work.

```
self.currentResponse("");
self.currentAssignee("");
```

I cannot get the values to clear. I had to do some hack-fu and added the line below that to just work around it for now:

```
$(".tb-assign").val("");
```

Comment: The whole cause of my issue was re-binding on every single return from polling to get new items. I switched out the code to replace all the old items with calling push() on the ObservableArray instead:

self.talkbackQueue.push(new_item);

So, now, the whole list doesn't rebind and I was able to remove a bunch of crap code.